# Loop animation - doesn't go

Tags: ios, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to repeat a sequence of animations, inside a LOOP, changing at each loop some parameters randomly. Here is the code. Anyone please knows why it doesn't work?
If I call it once with a button action, it works, but with a loop it doesn't.
Thanks a lot! Giuseppe

```
-(IBAction)startLoop:(id)sender {
    for (int i=1;i<10; i++) {
        [self animation2];
    }
}


-(id) animation2 {

    int max=500;
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coccinella2.png"];
    CALayer *myLayer = [CALayer layer];
    myLayer.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
    myLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 60);
    [myLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(arc4random()%(max), arc4random()%(max))];
    [myLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 60.0)];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:myLayer];


    //translation1
    CGPoint startPt = CGPointMake(arc4random()%(max),arc4random()%(max));
    CGPoint endPt = CGPointMake(arc4random()%(max),arc4random()%(max));
    CABasicAnimation *transl1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    transl1.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    transl1.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    transl1.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:startPt];
    transl1.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:endPt];
    transl1.duration = 2.0;
    transl1.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    transl1.beginTime = 0;

    //scale 1
    CABasicAnimation *scale1 = [CABasicAnimation 
                                animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scale1.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    [scale1 setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
    [scale1 setDuration:2.0f];
    scale1.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    scale1.beginTime = 0;

    //rotation1
    CABasicAnimation *rotation1 = [CABasicAnimation 
                                   animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotation1.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    [rotation1 setFromValue:DegreesToNumber(0)];
    [rotation1 setToValue:DegreesToNumber(90)];
    //rotation1.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [rotation1 setDuration:2.0f];
    rotation1.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotation1.beginTime = 0;

    //group
    CAAnimationGroup* group = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    [group setDuration: 6.0];
    group.removedOnCompletion = FALSE;
    group.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    [group setAnimations: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:scale1, transl1, rotation1, nil]];
    [myLayer addAnimation: group forKey:  nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't repeat the annotation 10 times but starts 10 animations right away. If your goal is to start the animations after the previous one ended you should try using an `NSTimer`.

Comment: thank you, my goal is to repeat continuously the animation, for example every 0.1 sec, how could I invoke the method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an NSTimer to trigger each group of animations at a different time, or you can set the beginTime on each group, with code like this:

```
group.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay;
```

For animations, using the beginTime gives more accurate timing, since CA is run on a separate thread and doesn't stall like NSTimers if your app gets busy.

Comment: thank you, my goal is to repeat continuously the animation, for example every 0.1 sec, how could I invoke the method "animation2"?

Comment: If you want the animation to repeat, don't use a for loop and create multiple animations. Set the repeatCount property on the group animation and the system will do it for you in one easy step. Do you want each step to pick up where the other one left off? If so, you will want to set the removedOnCompletion property to false, and set the fillMode to kCAFillModeForwards. (Do those last 2 things for all the individual animations, and set removedOnCompletion for both the individual animations AND the group.)